# Photoshop JPEG won’t open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have scanned old map (no grid ref etc) and then assembled high res JPEG in Photoshop (but obviously could save in other file format, e.g., TIFF) I am now trying to georeference in QGIS 3 but on trying import raster I only have weird coloured box in middle of Georeferencer (where my map) should be. I can open other JPEGs (not photoshopped) but don’t understand what doing wrong. Is there something embedded in PS JPEGs that QGIS doesn’t like. Do I have to run through image converter? If so, what? I am running on a Mac.

Comment: most likely Photoshop compression on the jpeg is causing this, to help post the original (or link) file and can help resolve this.

Comment: @Mapperz thanks for reply. Probably a dumb question but will this forum allow me to copy/paste large jpeg?

Comment: it will end up on imgur (png) if you can put it on a file sharing site like https://www.myairbridge.com/en/ will allow you to share 2gb for a limited time without login.

Comment: I think I might have cracked it. I saved in PS  as png and it seems to be working in QGIS. For future ref how do ppl edit and then output for use in QGIS generally. What program do you use if you need edit before using in QGIS?  Thanks again as I’m historian and GIS is tight learning curve for me!